# How to change reference popup tab position in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Is there any way to change code reference popup tab position in VS Code? It sometimes too much annoying when move cursor from one line to its top line. And most of time its getting clicked and open in browser that is super annoying.

Is there any way to change its position in any side or corner?

[image: VS code reference tab]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not much you can do built-in to change where the documentation appears.

There is a setting: `Editor > Hover: Above` true/false but `false` just sets it below the line.

But with the extension [Docs View](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bierner.docs-view) (built by a vscode team member) you can move that documentation into a view that you position in the Side Bar (where the Explorer normally is), the Panel or the new Side Panel (in v1.64 due this week).

And then disable: `Editor > Hover: Enabled`.

> In my testing, the extension does not trigger upon a hover, you have to click on an item to trigger new documentation.  That might be a bug in the extension, it is supposed to track cursor position (but that is in the Insiders Build, maybe it is better in Stable).

Comment: Yes this extension trigger on hover on my side. And place it in bottom is another worst steps by the way hahaa. But I found a solution, just change hover delay by 2 seconds and its fine now.

Comment: You can put the `Docs View` into the Side Bar (on the left) or into the new Side Panel (on the right) as well - not only the bottom Panel.